# How to write a newline character to a text file in binary mode

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a text file that contains all 54607 printable characters, but each line should only be 80 characters long for readability.

```
utf_all = ' !"#$'...'
lines   = '\n'.join(utf_all[i:i+80] for i in range(0, 54607, 80))
file    = open('allchars.txt', 'w').write(lines)
```

That returns an error message

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 193-243: character maps to `<undefined>`

If I try encoding the characters and writing in binary mode it ignores the newline \n and puts the entire string into one line and appends a newline to the end of the file.

Comment: Why would you open a text file in binary mode? Why would you not specify the encoding when opening the file? Why would you think that there's only 54607 printable characters?

Comment: The default write mode is text. Use `open('filename', 'wb')` to write in binary mode.

Comment: I don't see where your newline is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code, as it is, works fine for me in python3.5. However you open the file as text file, that's not what you wanted?

If I replace it with

```
open('allchars.txt', 'wb').write(lines)
```

then I had to add `encode('utf-8')` to `lines`:

```
file    = open('allchars.txt', 'wb').write(lines.encode('utf-8'))
```

EDIT:
my code for this:

```
utf_all = ''.join([chr(i)  for i in range(2**16)])
lines   = '\n'.join(utf_all[i:i+80] for i in range(0, 54607, 80))
file    = open('allchars.txt', 'wb').write(lines.encode('utf-8'))
```

my text editor will open this an wrap after 80 chars (`gedit`)

Comment: Where did you acquire the `utf_all` value?

Comment: see my updated anser